# Long response time with Yii2 query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, yii

I'm developing a php web application using yii.

I have written a small query for access a mysql table and I notice that with a Yii query the performance in terms or response time are much slower than using PDO.

Here a minimal code to reproduce the problem:

```
<?php

namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;

class TestController extends Controller {

public function actionTest1(){

    $start = round(microtime(true)*1000);

    $col = 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_database';
    $db = new \PDO($col , 'user', 'pwd');
    $sql = $db->prepare("SELECT id FROM user_content");
    $sql->execute(); 
    $res = $sql->fetchAll();
    echo "Execution time (ms):".(round(microtime(true)*1000) - $start);
}


public function actionTest2(){


    //**** YII db configuration
    // return [
    //     'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
    //     'dsn' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=my_database',
    //     'username' => 'user',
    //     'password' => 'pwd',
    //     'charset' => 'utf8',
    // ];

    $start = round(microtime(true)*1000);
    $sql = "SELECT id FROM user_conten";
    $result = Yii::$app->db->createCommand($sql)->execute();

    echo "Execution time (ms):".(round(microtime(true)*1000) - $start);
    }
 }
```

In the two cases the printed execution time is pretty small 1-2ms but the time of response monitored with chrome dev tools is very different.
In test 1 it's like 50-70ms while in the second case it's about 500ms.

[Case 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2uMAF.png)

[Case 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGbHS.png)

Anyone has an explanation of this behavior? (Yii debug is disabled)

Thank you!

Comment: `db` component is using `PDO` and you compare it with `mysqli`.

Comment: Why u r not using predefined db functions in yii..findAll(), findbypk() ?

Comment: Thank you all for responses and corrections. @Bizley I have corrected the sample code to use PDO and retest again with the same results.

Comment: Run the code with debug enabled and use Yii's debug toolbar to see what is taking long. Also, to ensure your results are not the outliers, you should run this 1000s of times using a tool like Apache Benchmark.

Comment: @RahulPawar because i start from a ActiveRecord::find***() command with this strange (for me) performance and I tried this to see if something changed.

Comment: @topher I don't think they are outliers. The performance difference is large, constant and it appears (every time in my multiple, not thousands but multiple, tests) as soon as I use Yii methods. I will try too check Yii debug to find out something.